# Resolving URLs in CSS using Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

How do you maintain folder structure of images used in CSS/SCSS files using Webpack 3+?

I don't want to keep the entire file path of an image, but I want more than just `[name].[ext]`

For instance, consider the following folder structure:

```
/
/app.js
/src
    /styles
    /images
        main-image.png
        /backgrounds
            my-bg.png
/dist
    /img
        /backgrounds
```

In my webpack.config file, I have the following loader for my images:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader?limit=1000000',
    options: {
        name: '/img/[name].[ext]'
    }
},
```

given the other configuration I have established (but not shown), including aliases, the loader shown above will dump all images in my `/dist/img/` folder, preserving file name and extension. This means that my background image that was originally `/src/images/backgrounds/my-bg.png` ends up at `/dist/img/my-bg.png`

My question is, how can I get webpack to preserve the `background` directory when moving the BG image to `dist`?

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
    //include: path.join(__dirname, 'myImages'),
    loader: 'file-loader?limit=1000000',
    options: {
        name: '/img/[path]/[name].[ext]'
    }
},
```

This config doesn't work because the resulting file path in CSS becomes `/img/src/images/backgrounds/my-bg.png`

What other configs do I need to achieve my desired results?

Here is the SCSS thats using the background image:

```
background: {
  image: url('images/backgrounds/my-bg.png');
  ...
}
```

For more info on file paths and the CSS-loader, i found this helpful: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#root-relative-urls